# AngularJS: Load resources from one project into another

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, angular-ui-router

I have two Spring Boot projects, Project1 and Project2. I have angular code in both the projects under 'static' folder. I am trying to route to the resources in Project2 from Project1 as below,

**src/main/resources/static/index.html (in Project1)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a ui-sref="spendCar">Click here to go to Spend Cat of Project2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**src/main/resources/static/app.js (in Project1)**

```
var proj1 = angular.module('proj1', ['ui.router']);

proj1.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    })
    .state('spendcat', {
        url: '/spendcat',
        templateUrl : 'http://localhost:8090/spendcat' //calling Project2's end point
    });

});
```

In Project2 I have a controller as below,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spendcat")
@CrossOrigin
public class SpendCatController {

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSpendCatPage() {
    return "spendcatpage";    //spendcatpage.html is under 'static' folder.
}
}
```

**src/main/resources/static/spendcatpage.html (in Project2)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sc.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Welcome to spend category page</div>

<input type="button" onclick="doClick()" value="Click Here">
</body>
</html>
```

I get error when "Click Here" button is clicked. If the javascript function doClick() is directly included in html file, then it works. Please suggest me how to load all resources of project2 in project1.

Comment: show your doClick function.

Comment: Not sure if it's a type or not but in the first block of code you've put `<a ui-sref="spendCar">Click here to go to Spend Cat of Project2</a>`, one says SpendCar the other says spendCat

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. It should be ui-sref="spendcat". I edited.